# Объединить все значения с одинаковым ключом

Tags: javascript, массивы, typescript, объекты

Проблема такая: надо переконвертировать массив из объектов с возможно 
одинаковыми значениями **filename**.Например

```
input: 
   {filename:'test.txt',content:'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'}
   {filename:'test.txt',content:' - fish text for devcelopers'}
   {filename:'test2.txt',content:'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... FOREVER!!!!!'}
   {filename:'test3.txt',content:'User admin pasted lorem ipsum to his project'}
 Предпологаемый output:
   {filename:'test.txt',content:'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... - fish text for devcelopers'}
   {filename:'test2.txt',content:'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... FOREVER!!!!!'}
   {filename:'test3.txt',content:'User admin pasted lorem ipsum to his project'}
```

Вот код на TypeScript:

```
function concat(filesdata:Array<FileData>):Promise<any>{
console.log("CONCATINATION OF FILES:",filesdata);
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    let files:Array<File> = [];

    filesdata.forEach(file => {
        files.push(file.toParent());
    });

    console.log("CONCATED FILES:",files);
    resolve(files);
});
}
```

И сами типы

```
class File{    
        public filename:string;    
        public content:string;    
   constructor(filename:string,content:string){
       this.filename = filename;
       this.content = content;
   }

   }

class FileData extends File
{

private _hash:string;
private err:Function;

  constructor(
     filename:string,content:string,hash:string,errorHander:Function
)
{
        super(filename,content);
        this.err = errorHander;
        if(this.hash != hash)this.err("Hashes not match!!!");
        this._hash = hash;
    }

toParent():File{
    return new File(super.filename,super.content);
}

checkHash(hash:string):boolean{
    return this.hash === hash;
}

get content():string{
    return super.content;
}
set content(value){
    super.content = value;
}

get filename():string{
    return super.filename;
}
set filename(value){
    super.filename = value;
}

get hash():string{
    return hash(super.content);
}
set hash(value){
    throw new Error("Field hash is read-only");
}
}
```

**Помогите**

Answer (score 0):

```js
function concat(filesdata: FileData[]): File[] {
  console.log("CONCATINATION OF FILES:", filesdata);
  const files: File[] = [];
  for (const fileData of filesdata) {
    if (!files.some((file) => {
        if (file.filename === fileData.filename) {
          file.content += fileData.content;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      })) {
      files.push(fileData);
    }
  }
  console.log("CONCATED FILES:", files);
  return files;
}
```

Думаю, что промис здесь не нужен.